# How to update distribution in google cloud cdn?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just started using google cloud cdn, moving from aws in my company.

In aws we can server static sites with s3 using ssl (with CloudFront). However when I update s3, I needed to update my distribution in cloudfront too.

In GCP I already setup Load balancer which includes cloud cdn pointing to my cloud storage. However I see no option to refresh the distribution. If i update my site in Cloud storage, how do I refresh my cdn?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to manually initiate CDN cache updating in GCP.

You can however use the [versioned URLs](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/best-practices#versioned-urls) to serve updated content to users;

> Versioning content serves a different version of the same content,
> effectively removing it by showing users new content before the cache
> entry expires. Because versioning is free and easy to use, we
> recommend that you use versioning as the default approach for updating
> cacheable content.

You can also influence bahevior of how often content is being updated by `max-age` value ([expiration time](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#expiration)) and here's more on [Cache Control in GCP buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata#cache-control).

> Note that if you allow caching, at download time you may see older
> versions of objects after uploading a newer replacement object. Note
> also that because objects can be cached at various places on the
> Internet there is no way to force a cached object to expire globally
> (unlike the way you can force your browser to refresh its cache). If
> you want to prevent serving cached versions of publicly readable
> objects, set "Cache-Control:no-cache, max-age=0" on the object.

You can also [change caching settings on already uploaded data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/setmeta) with `gcloud`.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible both in the Google Cloud Console and gcloud command-line tool.[1]

You can invalidate a single page:

```
gcloud compute url-maps invalidate-cdn-cache LOAD_BALANCER_NAME \
    --host HOSTNAME \
    --path "/images/file.jpg"
```

You can invalidate a directory:

```
gcloud compute url-maps invalidate-cdn-cache LOAD_BALANCER_NAME \
    --host HOSTNAME \
    --path "/images/*"
```

Or you can invalidate everything:

```
gcloud compute url-maps invalidate-cdn-cache LOAD_BALANCER_NAME \
    --host HOSTNAME \
    --path "/*"
```

In all cases you can exclude the `--host` parameter if you want this to apply to all hosts.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/invalidating-cached-content